# How can i move image in ms word using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

i want replace mergefiled with image
and i did that.
now I want to move image up a bit like using mouse in ms word.
how can i do that?
here is my code.

```
//hash = values for find, field = mergefields in word document
foreach (string s in hash.Keys)//if (hash key == field) 
            {
                hashVal = hash[s].ToString();


                Find findObj = app.Selection.Find;

                findObj.ClearFormatting();
                findObj.Text = frontM + fdName + backM; //=mergeField


                if (findObj.Text.Equals(frontM + s + backM))
                {
                    merge.Select();
                    app.Selection.TypeBackspace();


                    word.InlineShapes.AddPicture(hashVal, true, false, app.Selection.Range).ConvertToShape().WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapFront;
                    //app.Selection.MoveUp(); ????????
                }   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Relocate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.relocate(v=office.11).aspx) as follows:

```
rangeToMove.Relocate(WdRelocate.wdRelocateUp);
```

See [VBA documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192827.aspx) for details and more examples.

Comment: thank you for your comment,is it possible in c#?it is seems like for vba

Comment: I replaced example slightly. VBA documentation is better so I left link to it.